# Can I use 2 different StorageClass for the same storage provisioner type?

Tags: kubernetes

We have a Storageclass with an nfs provisioner and a reclaimPolicy: Delete. I created a separated StorageClass with the **reclaimPolicy: Retain** because Kafka needs to have the data persisted. One coworker told me that if I create a second StorageClass with the same provisioning source kubernetes can confuses the volumes and could overwrite data in the wrong volume. He recommends to declare the "reclaimPolicy: Retain", doing manually the PersistentVolumes. Using the already declared initial StorageClass.

I can not find this supposedly bad effect of using more than one StorageClass for the same provisioner. In fact, after reading the official k8s documentation I have the feeling that recommends the opposite thing:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#introduction

*A StorageClass provides a way for administrators to describe the “classes” of storage they offer. Different classes might map to quality-of-service levels, or to backup policies, or to arbitrary policies determined by the cluster administrators. **Kubernetes itself is unopinionated about what classes represent.** This concept is sometimes called “profiles” in other storage systems*

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can create multiple storage classes for same storage provider.

You can create one for 'reclaimPolicy: Delete' and second one for 'reclaimPolicy: Retain'